# Upper bound for $(1+x)^{1/2}$ where $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

> I am trying to find an upper bound, which is an algebraic function in $x$, for $(1+x)^{1/2}$ for $x>0$.

Note that $x$ need not be less than $1$. Binomial expansion can be used if $x<1$ but here $x$ can be an arbitrary positive real number. Any ideas?

Comment: $(1+x)^{1/2}$ is an algebraic function.  Are you looking for a polynomial upper bound?

Comment: @YuvalPeres True. I was hoping for an upper bound of the form $\sum x^i$ (finite sum) where $i$ can be rational. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1+x)^{1/2} \le  1+x^{1/2}$ for $x\ge 0$, as is verified by squaring.